# How to edit table in locked ESRI StreetMap data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, file-geodatabase

Preface: I'm newer to GIS, but know the basics of ArcMap. I'm using ArcMap 10.1 on a 64bit.

I've been working with the new 2014 Release 3 of North America StreetMap Premium (TomTom) for ArcGIS, but am unable to edit the data table in the Streets layer (I'm able to edit Highways, etc.). I've tried to uncompress file gdb, but it's failed twice, possibly because of how large the dataset is.

I wanted to try to open up the Streets file in Microsoft Access and query the data that way, but it can't be opened in whatever format it is (I've tried creating shapefiles, as well as the original .gdb).

Anyone have suggestions or has worked with this set of data?

Comment: Select the features you want and save the selection as a shapefile (or copy features to file geodatabase).

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to export any of those feature classes or uncompress the geodatabase.

From the [StreetMap Premium for ArcGIS Technical Restrictions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/arcgis-content/029700000056000000.htm):

> The detailed street layers (Geocode, Streets, and Routing_Streets) are
>   protected; therefore, **you cannot export these layers to a shapefile or
>   other feature class**. You also cannot use any ArcGIS function that will
>   read from the Geocode, Streets, or Routing_Streets Shape field and
>   output features into a feature class (i.e., buffer, intersect, etc.).

If you want to play around with the roads data for the North America, look at the free [North America Detailed Streets](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f38b87cc295541fb88513d1ed7cec9fd) from ArcGIS.com.

> U.S. and Canada Detailed Streets represents detailed streets,
>   interstate highways, and major roads within the United States and
>   Canada. The source used for this dataset is from 2007.

Comment: We've contacted our ESRI rep a while back and they provided us an unlocked .gdb of StreetMap

Comment: Ah, interesting, didn't know that is an option.